# Remove custom stopwords

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am trying to remove stopwords during an NLP pre-processing step. I use the `remove_stopwords()` function from `gensim` but would also like to add my own stopwords

```
# under this method, these custom stopwords still show up after processing
custom_stops = ["stopword1", "stopword2"]
data_text['text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item not in custom_stops])
# remove stopwords with gensim
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x.lower()))
# split the sentences into a list
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: str.split(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
custom_stops = ["stopword1", "stopword2"]
# remove stopwords with gensim
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['text'].apply(lambda x: remove_stopwords(x.lower()))
# split the sentence
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: str.split(x))
# remove the custom stopwords
data_text['filtered_text'] = data_text['filtered_text'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item.lower() not in custom_stops])
```

Answer (score 0):

After the program removed all the non-custom stopwords from the string, here is what you can do to remove the custom ones:

```
custom_stops = ["stopword1", "stopword2"]

s = 'I am very stopword1 and also very stopword2!'

for c in custom_stops:
    s = s.replace(c,'').replace('  ',' ')

print(s)
```

Output:

```
I am very and also very !
```